# How to apply material-ui button style to html-native button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

[pure-react-carousel](https://github.com/express-labs/pure-react-carousel) gives me an unstyled html button (`ButtonBack`) and I want to style it using [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#icon-buttons).

Placing buttons inside buttons is [not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386497/can-i-nest-button-inside-another-button).

What works is to assign the className prop manually:

```
<ButtonBack className={"MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained"}>
  <NavigateBeforeIcon />
</ButtonBack>
```

But it feels wrong, and also does not render as nice as an real Mui-Button.

Of course I could write my own css that mimics Muis but that feels wrong too.

Is there an easier/straight-forward way to this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by feels wrong? Wrong as in bad feeling or bad aesthetically?

Comment: How to know the names ("MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root")? They are hard coded - copied from some example. I would like to have something programmatic.

Comment: If that's your concern, why not just use `import {Button} from '@material-ui/core'`?

Comment: I need to use `ButtonBack` because it is triggers the carousel

Comment: Your updated answer still contains hard-coded css. I found an solution in on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { ButtonFirst } from 'pure-react-carousel';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const CustomButtonFirst = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Button component={ButtonFirst} ref={ref} {...props} />);

// This line is needed because the "disabled" is internal state of "ButtonFirst".
export default withStore(CustomButtonFirst, state => ({ disabled: state.currentSlide === 0 }));
```

Taken from:
https://github.com/express-labs/pure-react-carousel/issues/175