# How to disable group-* on a specific child element in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, sveltekit

I have a button in a button setup, what should I put in the child button(or somewhere) so it doesn't change the color of the parent when I click or hover the child button?

```
   <button class="group hover:bg-blue-100 active:bg-blue-200" on:click={test}>
      
      <div  class="group-hover:bg-sky-100 group-active:bg-sky-200">
           Hello
      </div>

      <button class="???????????" on:click|stopPropagation={clickMe}>
          Click Me
      <button/>
   <button/>
```

Comment: Having interactive elements (like buttons) within buttons is invalid.

Comment: Your structure is really complicated for I don't know why, you can check at button groups: https://flowbite.com/docs/components/button-group/, HTML / CSS is simple, keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see a small issue. I don't think it's a valid HTML markup to nest a button within another button. If you check your browser dev tools, you would notice the button is duplicated in a weird way. You can read more about this via [this question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39386695/9775615).

Also I noticed you're using `active:bg-blue-200` and `group-active:bg-sky-200` in your markup, which will trigger the 'active' selector when you click on the child button. So I removed it.

Here's the modified code:

```
   <div class="group hover:bg-blue-100" on:click={test}>
      <div  class="group-hover:bg-sky-100">
           Hello
      </div>

      <button class="???????????" on:click|stopPropagation={clickMe}>
          Click Me
      <button/>
   <div/>
```

However, if you are looking to entirely modify the background of the parent div when the button is clicked, then you might have to separate the elements. The  button is inheriting the hover state of its parent, because it's part of the parent div. When you hover over the button, you're technically also hovering over the parent div.

Maybe do something like:

```
   <div class="relative" on:click={test}>
     <div class="group hover:bg-blue-100">
        <div  class="group-hover:bg-sky-100">
            Hello
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="absolute">
      <button class="???????????" on:click|stopPropagation={clickMe}>
          Click Me
      <button/>
    </div>
   <div/>
```

This way, the button no longer shares the same parent as the 'hello' div and will not trigger the background change. I'm not sure how your layout is supposed to be exactly but you get the idea. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Having `click` events on divs is inaccessible and should be avoided.

Comment: Yes you're right @H.B. I'm not sure what the OP is trying to do but since they used a button there before, I just had to retain it. Hopefully we get more context